# Creating a custom slider for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to create a custom vertical slider for my iPhone app, simply because the UISlider is to narrow. It is going to be used as a throttle "stick" for my remote controlled helicopter. 
I managed to rotate the slider in xcode with

```
throttleSlider.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3*M_PI_2);
```

but I think this is quite ugly since the slider still appear horizontally on my storyboard. Also, I can not find anyway to make the slider wider.

How will I approach this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: storyboard won't reflect changes you perform programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the application I am developing right now we needed a custom slider. It had to be wider (44pixels wide, the default size of a table view cell). We accomplished our goal by using stretchable images and adjusting the properties of the slider:

```
UIImage* sliderCenterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderCenter.png"];
[slider setThumbImage:sliderCenterImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *leftStretch2 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderLeft.png"]
                             stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
slider setMinimumTrackImage:leftStretch2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIImage *rightStretch = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderRight.png"]
                          stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:1.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[slider setMaximumTrackImage:rightStretch2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This way I got an slider that fulfills a whole cell of a tableView.
thumbImage is the image that represents the middle of the slider (the one you interact with, by default a round dot), minimumTrackImage will be the part on the left of the slider (the one that by default is blue), and maximumTrackImage is the part usually left blank on the right of the center of the slider. There are more properties of the UISlider that allow further customization. Take a look at [UISlider developer reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great info! Thank you. Why double up of `[slider setMaximumTrackImage:rightStretch2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];`?

Comment: @Wilhelmsen sorry, problem with copy paste! I'll edit to fix it.

Comment: Btw, in which method do you implement this? When slider is updated? ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Since my slider is inside a TableViewCell, this code is inside the CellForRowAtIndexPath method. If your slider is inside a normal view, I would place that code inside ViewDidLoad, after the view is created but before it appears on screen.

Comment: Great! A bit confusing since I am rotating the slider but your method works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I've used this implementation of `UICustomSwitch` before, from Catamount Software's blog:

[UICustomSwitch](http://www.catamount.com/blog/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/)

It attempts to customize the familiar `UISwitch` class, but it accomplishes this by subclassing `UISlider`, and replacing the normal switch imagery with custom images.  You could download this code, then just replace the included images with something that you draw yourself.

Because this was intended to be a switch, which only has on and off settings, you'll see that it responds to touches with this:

```objc
[self setOn:on animated:YES];
```

Just get rid of the code that calls `setOn:animated:` so that the slider doesn't force its value all the way to 0.0 or 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

As an updated answer, stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth is deprecated. It is advised to use

[resizableImageWithCapInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:)

For a custom slider in swift:

```
    var thumb = UIImage(named: "slider_thumb")
    musicSlider.setThumbImage(thumb, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    var left = UIImage(named: "left_slide")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0,left: 0.0,bottom: 0.0,right: 0.0))
    musicSlider.setMinimumTrackImage(left, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    var right = UIImage(named: "right_slide")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0,left: 0.0,bottom: 0.0,right: 0.0))
    musicSlider.setMaximumTrackImage(right, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

The UIEdgeInserts specify the buffer of the image that won't get resized. so left:15.0 would mean the area 15 pixels in from the left will not get resized. In my case I didn't care so it was all zero.

As a note, the images themselves are what is making the slider bar wider. My thumb image is 35 pixels in height, my left and right slider images are 20 pixels in height. All are sliced and resizable from Images.xcassets (where images should be kept)